# TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments error while creating aiopg Pool

Tags: python, python-asyncio, tornado, aiopg

I have written the below code for some unit testing. Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.I know I am missing somthing but cant figure it out.

```
class testing(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.reset())

    async def reset(self):
        async with self.get_db().acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute('DELETE FROM vehicles')

    def get_db(self):
        '''
        Instantiate the database.
        '''
        return aiopg.Pool(
            None, 1, 10, None, 5,
            enable_json=True, enable_hstore=True,
            enable_uuid=True, echo=True, on_connect=None,
            pool_recycle=True,
            host='db' if os.getenv('IN_DOCKER') == 'true' \
                else options.db_host,
            port=options.db_port,
            user=options.db_user,
            password=options.db_password,
            dbname=options.db_database
        )

    def get_app(self):
        return Application(self.get_db())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 33, in setUp
    loop.run_until_complete(self.reset())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "tests.py", line 36, in reset
    async with self.get_db().acquire() as conn:
  File "tests.py", line 54, in get_db
    dbname=options.db_database
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 positional arguments (and 6 keyword-only arguments) were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aiopg.Pool`[[1]](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiopg/pool.html) expects the positional arguments

`dsn, minsize, maxsize, timeout`

You have given 5 positional arguments

`None, 1, 10, None, 5`

That's one argument too much.

Comment: good spot! thank you.

now i'm getting 
  File "tests.py", line 62, in get_db
    dbname=options.db_database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiopg/pool.py", line 46, in __init__
    self._loop = get_running_loop(kwargs.pop('loop', None) is not None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiopg/utils.py", line 26, in get_running_loop
    loop = __get_running_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiopg/utils.py", line 21, in __get_running_loop
    raise RuntimeError('no running event loop')
RuntimeError: no running event loop

Comment: Ah yeah, the asyncio things.. I'd recommend adding the new information to the question, having to backformat the stack trace does not make it easier to see what is going on - but if a search for this error did not yield helpful information, that might justify to open a new question.